# Unable to connect to a target server via SSH from a GitLab pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

I have set up .gitlab-ci.yml. I am unable to login to the production server from gitlab. I have set the private and public key variables of my server in GITLAB but still getting timeout error in pipeline.

```
job1: 
 stage: build1
 script:
   - mvn package
 variables:
  SSH_PUBLIC_key: "$SSH_PUBLIC_key"
  SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
 artifacts:
  paths:
  - server
 script:
   - scp "myjar" root@"myIP":/tmp


job1:
 stage: build1
 script:
   - mvn package
 variables:
  SSH_PUBLIC_key: "$SSH_PUBLIC_key"
  SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
 artifacts:
  paths:
  - server
 script:
   - scp "myjar" root@"myIP":/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

timeout error comes, when the instance (in your case the production instance) is not reachable from GitLab (can be hosted on VM, Kubernetes, etc). Please check if you are able to perform telnet/ssh manually from the GitLab hosted VM

Replace myIP with proper values and see if that helps.

```
telnet <myIP> 22
ssh <myIP>
```